# How to write data received from the server after .fetch() in model and passed to template?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, fetch

Good day! I'm new in backbone and i writing a simple little application based backbone + jquerymobile. 
When I get data from the server, I need to properly transfer the data to the view, where they are passed to the template. Because the `.fetch()` asynchronous, i cant just pass in render my model. How can I do so that would after `.fetch()` data received from the server, written in the model and then passed to the template?

```
//template
<script type="text/html" class="template" id="profile-form">
 <div data-role="header">
    <h3>Step 4</h3>
    <a href="#main" data-theme="a">Home</a>
    <a href="#logout" data-theme="a">logout</a>
 </div>
 <div data-role="content">
     <h2 class="ui-li-heading"><%= username %></h2>
     <p class="ui-li-desc"><strong><%= phone %></strong></p>
 </div>
</script>

// model
var UserInfo = Backbone.Model.extend({
url: appConfig.baseURL + "users/",
});

// routes
profileInfo: function () {
    var user = new UserInfo()
    this.changePage(new ProfilePageView({ model: user }));
},

// view
var ProfilePageView = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize: function () {
    this.template = $.tpl['profile-form'];
},

render: function (eventName) {
    $(that.el).html(that.template());
    return this;
}
});
```

I trying to add this part in my render in view. Its works, but my styles are not working. 
I'm not quite sure that I did the right thing by putting fetch in render, can advise how to do correctly?

```
    var that = this
    this.model.fetch({
        data: $.param({email: localStorage.getItem('user_email')}),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function (response) {
            $(that.el).html(that.template(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response))));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built-in events to decouple everything.  Fetching is one step, updating is distinct.  In your view do:

```
initialize: function () {
    this.template = $('#profile-form').html();
    this.listenToOnce(this.model, 'sync', function(){ 
        this.render();
        //this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render, this);
 }, this);
},
```

Every time the model has the *set* method called (and some attribute changes) it will trigger a **change** event.  The *listenTo* method will run a callback when that happens.  Another event you might want is **sync** which is called after a successful fetch.  Sometimes you might need *listenToOnce* if you only want to render on the first **sync** and then control it yourself after that.

Your template probably needs its parameters passed in too:

```
render: function(){
    $(this.el).html(_.template(this.template, this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
}
```

In terms of when to fetch, that's up to you a bit.  You could fetch regularly or only when someone routes to that page.  In the code you give I would do something like:

```
profileInfo: function () {
    var user = new UserInfo();
    user.fetch();
    this.changePage(new ProfilePageView({ model: user }));
}
```

Comment: It seems that I need, but there is a problem. `render` run twice, i put `console.log(this.model.toJSON())` in begin of my `render` and `console.log("success")` in success option in fetch(). At first it output empty object, next error about my elements not found, next correct Object with all attributes and at last it output "success". I think  i need to get object before it passed to the template, but not after this.

Comment: So replace the **change** line with this line `this.listenToOnce(this.model, 'sync', function(){ this.render(); this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render, this); }, this)`

Comment: Now `success` and correct object swapped, but at first still shows empty `Object {}` and reference error.

Comment: And if i change `console.log(this.model.toJSON())` to `console.log(this.model)` in `render` its output two equal strings o_O

Comment: So here's what's going on there.  Console.log(this.model) will call .toJSON for what it displays to screen. model.toJson will grab the important attributes and make a JSON object out of them.  So the fact that they show the same thing is no surprise.  However this.template(this.model) will not load the correct info.  

The other issue you see is that the model object is empty until after a 'sync'.  So any console.logs which take place prior to a 'sync' will display an empty object.  If the template is not loading you can use _.template(this.template, this.model.toJson());

Comment: I changed to your code and got next error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object function (data) {
       return render.call (this, data, _);
     } Has no method 'replace'` Why this method takes its as  `this.template`. Where i was wrong?

Comment: So I didn't expect to give you exact code as I don't have the whole picture, but try adjusting the this.template to

    this.template = $('#profile-form').html();

Comment: Is your backend public?  Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle of your code working.  http://jsfiddle.net/LS75N/1/ I did run into your replace error whenever the template was not loading properly.  Be sure that your code is in an onReady area, so that the html template is loaded first!